# Delete rectangle on Click using Leaflet.Draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to delete the rectangle just after it has been created i have tried to do like this:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
var type = e.layerType,
layer = e.layer;

if (type === 'rectangle') {
  layer.on('click', function (event) {
    alert(event.target.getLatLngs());
    event.target.removeControl();
  });
}
```

The reason is that, i like to get all markers inside the rectangle. But after i have got the Lat and lng, i just want to remove/delete it again.
Currently i have it on a click event, while i debug.
Best Regard Morten Starck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have found an solution to my problem:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
      layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.clearLayers();
    if (type === 'rectangle') {
      //console.log(layer.getLatLngs());
      //console.log(layer.getBounds());
      //console.log(layer.getBounds().toBBoxString());
      //console.log(layer);
      $.get(ol.url('~/Map/FetchNewMarkers'), { bound: layer.getBounds().toBBoxString() }, function (data) {
        //console.log('From Controller: ' + data);
      });

    }
    //drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  });
```

Which was to remove the `drawItems.addLayer(layer)`  from the event.